# How to retreive sum(amount) column by yearly basis?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, aggregate-functions

I Have the table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists `outwardpayments`(
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `companyname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `invoicenumber` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `typeofservice` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `amount` INT(20) NOT NULL,
  `isapproved` BOOLEAN,
  `ispaid` BOOLEAN,
  `invoicedate` varchar(255),
  `padidate` datetime,
 PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

such that I want sum(amount) and (paiddate) which is of yearly basis so that I'll display a bar chart showing amount vs years. (Yearly Spendings)

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses following an INT is largely meaningless

Comment: Then how should I declare for amount ?

Comment: Well if 'amount' is money, then it's usually declared as DECIMAL. If it's a genuine integer, then INT on its own, no parentheses, is just fine

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: okay fine then but I didn't get the answer what am I asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do something like this:

```
Select YEAR(paiddate),sum(amount)
from yourtable
group by YEAR(paiddate);
```

Read more about [year](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)